# Can I change push notification sound when app is closed?

Tags: android, audio, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

When I send notifications to android phones via GCM i send a sound name which is played if the app is running, or when the user click the notification.

My question is can i change the sound of the notification ? not when the user click on notification but when the notification pop up in the phone. I know it's possible, [Yo app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.justyo) plays sound "YO" when the notification push pop up.

Sorry for my english :s and thank you for help !

Answer (score 0):

When you build a notification, you can set a sound to the notification using `setSound(uri)`.

```
public NotificationCompat.Builder setSound (Uri sound)

Set the sound to play. It will play on the default stream.
```

Or you can use `setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)` for playing the default sound.

For example :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
  .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
  .setTicker (text)
  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
  .setContentText (text)
  .setContentTitle(title)
  .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(text))
  .setAutoCancel(true).setNumber (4)
  .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

As far as I know, this sound is played when the notification is displayed (though I haven't checked). But if it doesn't, you can play the sound regardless of the notification in the code that shows the notification (in your broadcast receiver or intent service) before calling `mNotificationManager.notify`.